# Vue array computed via parameterized getter not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a list a discussion object containing an array of comments and each comment can hold an array of replies. I display the discussion this way:

```
<div v-for="comment in comments" v-bind:key="comment._id">
  <Comment :itemId="itemId" :comment="comment" />
  <Replies v-if="comment.replies.length > 0" :itemId="itemId" :comment="comment" />
</div>
<Button value="Load more" @clicked="loadMoreComments(itemId)" />
```

and Replies:

```
<div v-for="reply in replies" v-bind:key="reply._id">
  <Comment :itemId="itemId" :comment="reply" />
</div>
<Button :value="Load more" @clicked="loadChild()"/>
```

As you can see both use the same pattern. They differ in a computed property:

```
computed: {
  comments() {
    return this.$store.getters.DISCUSSION.comments.map(id => this.$store.getters.GET_COMMENT(id));
  },
  replies() {
    return this.$store.getters.GET_REPLIES(this.comment).map(id => this.$store.getters.GET_COMMENT(id));
  },
},
```

When I hit the Load more button for comments, new comments appear. But when I hit the Load more button in replies, then no new reply is displayed though I can see in debugger that the array was enlarged.

Vuex store submodule:

```
state: () => ({
  discussion: {
    incomplete: true,
    comments: [],
  },
  comments: {},
}),

getters: {
  DISCUSSION: state => state.discussion,
  GET_COMMENT: state => id => state.comments[id],
  GET_REPLIES: state => (comment) => {
    if (comment.allShown) {
      return comment.replies;
    }
    return comment.replies.slice(0, REPLY_LIMIT);
  },
},
mutations: {
  APPEND_COMMENTS: (state, payload) => {
    const { comments, incomplete, userId } = payload;
    state.discussion.incomplete = incomplete;
    const commentIds = [];
    comments.forEach(comment => processComment(state, comment, commentIds, userId));
    state.discussion.comments = state.discussion.comments.concat(commentIds);
  },
  PREPEND_COMMENTS: (state, payload) => {
    const { comments, userId } = payload;
    const commentIds = [];
    comments.forEach(comment => processComment(state, comment, commentIds, userId));
    state.discussion.comments = commentIds.concat(state.discussion.comments);
  },
  SET_REPLIES: (state, payload) => {
    console.log('SET_REPLIES');
    const { commentId, replies, userId, replace } = payload;
    const comment = state.comments[commentId];
    if (!comment) {
      return;
    }

    state.comments[commentId].showAll = true;
    const commentIds = [];
    replies.forEach(reply => processComment(state, reply, commentIds, userId));
    if (!comment.replies || comment.replies.length === 0 || replace) {
      state.comments[commentId].replies = commentIds;
    } else {
      state.comments[commentId].replies = comment.replies.concat(commentIds);
    }
  },
}

function processComment(state, comment, commentIds, userId) {
  if (comment.replies) {
    const repliesIds = [];
    comment.replies.forEach((reply) => {
      reply.voted = hasVoted(reply.votes, userId);
      state.comments[reply._id] = reply;
      repliesIds.push(reply._id);
    });
    comment.replies = repliesIds;
    comment.allShown = comment.replies.length < REPLY_LIMIT;
  } else if (!comment.parentId) {
    comment.replies = [];
    comment.allShown = false;
  }
  state.comments[comment._id] = comment;
  commentIds.push(comment._id);
}
```

The complete source code is there: https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/tree/comment_refactoring/spa

Here is minimum reproducible codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-taussig-v8u4b?file=/src/module.js

I have verified that this happens because of the getter with a parameter. When I put the reply in static array so I could use parameter-less getter, it started to work.

I follow this recommendation: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuex-best-practices-for-complex-objects/10143

Where is the issue?

Update:

One thing that smells is the mutation `GET_REPLIES` because it works on the passed object. So Vue has no chance to detect that the object is from the state. So I have rewritten it to pass only commentId and load the comment from the state, but it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guest you should replace `showAll` with `allShown` prop and also use `Vue.set` where you add new keys to `comments` object because due to Vue caveats Vuex doesn't see new props, see [caveats for objects](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects)

```
    SET_REPLIES: (state, payload) => {
      console.log("SET_REPLIES");
      const { commentId, replies, userId, replace } = payload;
      const comment = state.comments[commentId];
      if (!comment) {
        console.log(`Comment ${commentId} not found`);
        return;
      }

      state.comments[commentId].allShown = true;
      // state.comments[commentId].showAll = true;

...

function processComment(state, comment, commentIds, userId) {
  if (comment.replies) {
    const repliesIds = [];
    comment.replies.forEach(reply => {
      Vue.set(state.comments, reply._id, reply);
      // state.comments[reply._id] = reply;
      repliesIds.push(reply._id);
    });
    comment.replies = repliesIds;
    comment.allShown = comment.replies.length < 3;
  } else if (!comment.parentId) {
    comment.replies = [];
    comment.allShown = false;
  }
  Vue.set(state.comments, comment._id, comment);
  // state.comments[comment._id] = comment;
  commentIds.push(comment._id);
}
```

Also correct GET_REPLIES call like this:

```
  computed: {
    replies() {
      return this.$store.getters
        .GET_REPLIES(this.comment) // passing comment itself instead of its id
        .map(id => this.$store.getters.GET_COMMENT(id));
    }
  },
```

[corrected example](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-platform-eqkqk?file=/src/store.js)

Comment: Hello, I found that typo as well, but it did not help. Your sandbox is not working, "Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined"".

Comment: just correct GET_REPLIES call as I mentioned at the end of my answer

Comment: Vue.set(state.comments, comment._id, comment); is the game changer, thanks!